# How to install ipkg in CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, ipkg

I have started using CentOS recently. I have some packages which end with .ipk. I need to install a cross compiler and the steps in the compiler's manual says I should do the following:

```
ipkg install libstdc++6_4.1.2-r10_armv5te.ipk
```

I have tried to  install ipkg or opkg, but it didn't work. Can anyone tell how to install any of them or if there is an alternative to install .ipk file?

Comment: Don't. CentOS has it's own tools. Besides, installing alien tools to blindly follow some "apt-get fi fa fo fum" recipe *will* fail, the packages are organized differently than in Debian.

Comment: I got your point. But still I need ipkg can you tell me how to install it ?

Comment: Why do you need ipkg? I'm sure whatever it has in its default repos can be obtained in the EPEL repo as well.

Comment: I have to use to install .ipk files

Comment: What `.ipkg` files do you wish to install? Why?

Comment: I'm working on a robot and I need to install them to add the cross compiler

Comment: I didn't the question can you please remove the on hold?

Comment: If you need a cross compiler, look for that. I doubt you'll find it for CentOS (a *server* operating system), perhaps you'd have more luck with e.g. Fedora.

Comment: @vonbrand I have the cross compiler .tar.bz2 files I was able to install C cross compiler and now I need the ipkg to install C++ packages isn't there anyway to install .ipk in CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is a Redhat-Base distro and uses `YUM(Yellowdow Updater Modified)` engine, `Debian-base` distros such as mint, *untu and so on use `APT` enegine.

For more information about YUM engine you can read : [YUM guides](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Guides)

Comment: I know that I have to use yum , my question is how to use it to install ipkg

Comment: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2011-March/007215.html

Answer (score 1):

`ipkg` has been replaced by `opkg`.
Download source:

```
wget http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/opkg/opkg-0.2.1.tar.gz
```

Compile:

```
./configure
make
```

You **really** don't have to use `apt`!

Comment: it didn't work . Also there isn't a file named autoconfigure.sh